# how to call implementation class methods in run method without hardcoding

Tags: java, reflection, real-time

```
interface Myinterface
{
boolean run();
}

class MyClass implements Myintr
{
      boolean run()
      {
          boolean status=false;
           disp();//hard coded
           show();//hard coded
```

here above two methods are hard coded how can we call without hard coding
          }
          public void disp()
          {
                 System.out.println("Hello Person");
          }

```
      public void show()
      {
               System.out.println("Welcome");
       }

}

class Mainclass
{
public static void main(String args[])
{

   Class aClass=Class.forName("Myclass");
   Object obj=aClass.newInstance();
   Myinterface myinter=(Myinterface)obj.run();
```

}
  }

Answer (score 0):

Your question is extremely unclear, but I suspect you're looking for something like this:

MyInterface.java:

```
interface MyInterface {
    void run();
}
```

Impl1.java:

```
class Impl1 implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello Person");
    }
}
```

Impl2.java:

```
class Impl2 implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Welcome");
    }
}
```

MainClass.java:

```
class MainClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.mypackage.Impl1");
        Object obj = aClass.newInstance();
        MyInterface myinter = (MyInterface)obj;
        myinter.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: No,actually we need to call implementation class two methods from run() method based on method name,
For ex: if i want to call disp() method i'll call it,
it should be called dynamically based on our requirement we no need do any hardcode for calling methods like
 inside 
run()
{
disp();
}
this we should not do.